# Do any governments record and archive phone calls by leaders?

Tags: government, transparency

A current topic is the summary of a phone call made by the President of the U.S. I have read that no U.S. President since Nixon has recorded calls. Are there any countries/governments that do consider transparency and duty to history important enough to record phone calls made by leaders?

Comment: Do you maybe remember where you have read it? Recording phone calls for example to have proof in case of doubt sounds like best practice to me.

Comment: @Trilarion: One example is this Washington Post article: https://www.washingtonpost.com/national-security/2019/09/25/transcripts-presidential-calls-are-nearly-verbatim-not-exact-heres-how-it-works/

Comment: Thanks. Content is unfortunately behind a paywall, but maybe I can get access to it.

Comment: Apparently there is no such requirement for the Prime Minister of Australia. However his Government was scrutinized by the Senate over what seems to have been regarded as a failing of the PM to make a record of a conversation with Trump: https://www.canberratimes.com.au/story/6450212/no-records-of-morrison-trump-phone-call/